# What is the purpose of the Android @Widget annotation?

Tags: java, android

What is the purpose of the Android @Widget annotation (defined in [android/annotation/Widget.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/annotation/Widget.java))? I can't find any references to anything that might use it.

Edit: Yes, I have read the description in the Javadoc. It doesn't explain the purpose of the annotation, i.e. *why* one would want to use it. Is a @Widget-annotated class treated differently somehow?

Comment: Indicates a class is a widget usable by application developers to create UI.
This must be used in cases where:
The widget is not in the package android.widget
The widget extends android.view.ViewGroup